# why console gives me different output if i changed the order of input as below

Tags: javascript

> Hi, I am going through javascript concepts now. today i came across a
>   following question: i have tried with following example
>   in  browser console or firebug when i enter     `1 || true` it gives
>   output as 1    and when i enter `true || 1` it gives output `true`
>
> why?  please elaborate.    whether it is due to type conversion ?            > still i need satisfied answer.

Comment: Both `1` and `true` are truthy values.  The or operator is simply returning the first truthy value it comes across.  To illustrate this you can try `false || 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking whether the first argument to your or comparison is true. In javascript, an `OR` comparison returns true as soon as an argument is true.

`1` is `true`, and so is `true`, so it'll pick the first argument passed in both cases.

What you see is also used as short circuit, so you could check if a variable has a value, and if not, take the "default" after `||`.

For example, consider the following:

```
var a;
console.log(a || 'notSet');
```

will log `notSet`, because `a` is undefined and the "default" is picked.

or

```
true || (anything)
```

is short-circuit evaluated to true, so true would be logged.

Also see [mdn's documentation about logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: Interestingly, Chrome logs "static" for your example. I don't understand it. Chrome version: 48.0.2564.103 m.

Comment: Not in my chrome, which version are you using? I'm using 49.0.2623.47 beta (64-bit) and it logs 'notSet' @Stack0verflow

Comment: So, maybe it is a bug in version 48?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it should always log 'notSet' @Stack0verflow. nodejs also does this.

Comment: using firefox 41.0b9

Comment: @Stack0verflow not in my console

Comment: Also tried over chrome Version 48.0.2564.103 m. It outputs 'notSet' as per your example. Now i got it. Thanks to you Michel